# beamer : auto-gray out before pause

Tags: beamer

I understand that a variety of `beamer` commands can help with displaying parts of a page on consecutive slides (such as `\uncover`, `\only`, etc.)  so I can manage the effect that I want manually.  but I am wondering whether it can be automated:  is there a way to redefine `\pause` so that everything before the pause will automatically fade (to gray) to highlight the new segment only?

Regards, /iaw

PS: Till Tantau must be a genius! TikZ and Beamer are each incredible pieces of work.

Comment: Maybe `\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{0}}, again covered={\opaqueness<1->{50}}}` that should work with incremental overlays, but I dont think it will work with pause.

Answer (score 3):

I would discourage using `\pause`, instead use `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+>}`. That is more powerful and less typing effort, see [beamer package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 89.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}% see beamer documentation p 190
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+>}% see beamer documentation p 89

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item def
\item ghi
\item jkl
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you really need to redefine `\pause`, for example because you want to use `\tableofcontents[pausesections]` which is internally using `\pause`,  see my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345782/120953).