# How to highlight a specific section in beamer ToC?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a ToC with 5 sections, and I want 5 frames where there is on each one a table of contents with the *ith* section highlighted, and the other are shaded.

What I have so far is the following :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Overview} 
  \only<1>{
    \tableofcontents[sections={1}]
    \tableofcontents[sections={2-5},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
  }
  \only<2>{
    \tableofcontents[sections={1},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \tableofcontents[sections={2}]
    \tableofcontents[sections={3-5},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
  }
  \only<3>{
    \tableofcontents[sections={1,2},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \tableofcontents[sections={3}]
    \tableofcontents[sections={4-5},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
  }
  \only<4>{
    \tableofcontents[sections={1-3},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \tableofcontents[sections={4}]
    \tableofcontents[sections={5},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
  }
  \only<5>{
    \tableofcontents[sections={1-4},sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded]
    \tableofcontents[sections={5}]
  }
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I wonder whether there is a better way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You're right ! I have update my code.

Comment: A similar automatic approach might be `\begin{frame}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \tableofcontents[pausesections]
 \end{frame}`. Unfortunately I do not know how to recover the sections again. In your manual approach you should keep an eye on the spacing - every time you call `\tableofcontents`  additional space is added thus making the spacing inhomogeneous.

Comment: I tried your solution thanks. The problem is that my ToC is too dense, and at the end not so readable with all the items higlighted. That is why I just want one item be visible at time.

Answer (score 7):

After your `\begin{document}` put this code. It shall do it:

```
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan}
\tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\AtBeginSection[]{

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is only half the truth, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280436/how-to-highlight-a-specific-section-in-beamer-toc#comment675832_280436

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `currentsection` option and set a temporary value in the `section` counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\newcommand\tocforsect[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\safesection{\thesection}
  \setcounter{section}{#1}
  \tableofcontents[#2,currentsection]
  \setcounter{section}{\safesection}
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Overview}
  \only<1>{\tocforsect{1}{sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded}}
  \only<2>{\tocforsect{2}{sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded}}
  \only<3>{\tocforsect{3}{sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded}}
  \only<4>{\tocforsect{4}{sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded}}
  \only<5>{\tocforsect{5}{sectionstyle=shaded,subsectionstyle=shaded}}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a normal list that's easy:

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}% see beamer documentation p 190
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+>}% see beamer documentation p 89
```

Unfortunately, that does not work with `\tableofcontents[pausesections]` because this is internally using the far less powerful `\pause` command.

So I have tried to redefine the `\pause` command to call `\onslide` with an overlay specification that is desirable for our purpose. 
Actually, according to the [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 78 `\pause` usually does use `\onslide` internally already.

However, it does not seem possible to define commands with parameters inside of a frame (and `\pause` has one optional parameter, again see [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 78) and `\pause` is overridden at the beginning of a frame.

Consequently I am defining a new command in front of the frame and `\let` it inside of it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcommand{\mypause}[1][+]{\onslide<#1>}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Overview} 
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}% doc p 190
    \let\pause\mypause
    \tableofcontents[pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 5}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great! I guess this is also applicable to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252182/beamer-auto-gray-out-before-pause. Would you like to answer this?

Comment: @samcarter yes, thank you. I have answered it.

Comment: To define `\mypause` inside a frame, you may use `\newcommand\mypause[1][+]{\onslide<####1>}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Contents} 
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\begin{frame}{Frame 1.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1.2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1.3}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\begin{frame}{Frame 2.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2.2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 2.3}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 3}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\begin{frame}{Frame 3.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3.2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 3.3}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 4}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\begin{frame}{Frame 4.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4.2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 4.3}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 5}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\begin{frame}{Frame 5.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5.2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Frame 5.3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```