# Shade past sections in toc

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

How to shade the already presented sections in the table of contents, while keeping future sections fully visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use `pausesections` and recover previous sections while having future sections visible (implemented with a little help from [How to highlight a specific section in beamer ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280436/how-to-highlight-a-specific-section-in-beamer-toc)). This would display a sequenze of slides for all sections to be uncovered, but `<\value{section}>` will pick out the relevant overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\mypause}[1][+]{\onslide<#1>}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<\value{section}>
        \setbeamercovered{%
           still covered={\opaqueness<1->{100}},
           again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
        }
        \let\pause\mypause
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}

\section{SECT I}

\subsection{I.1}
\begin{frame}I.1\end{frame}

\subsection{I.2}
\begin{frame}I.2\end{frame}

\section{SECT II}
\begin{frame}II frame 1\end{frame}
\begin{frame}II frame 2\end{frame}

\section{SECT III}
\subsection{III.1}
\begin{frame}III.1\end{frame}

\subsection{III.2}
\begin{frame}III.2\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]