# Beamer, shadow previous and current sections

Tags: beamer

I'm new to beamer, I'm trying to include a table of contents at the end of each section with the current and previous sections shadowed and all the following shown.
To be more clear, in the picture below I'd like also Section 1 to be shadowed

[image: explanation]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Table of content}
\tableofcontents[sectionstyle=shaded/show,subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/show]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add your table of contents _after_ `\section{Section 3}` and without special options...

Comment: The problem with that is that I have a new frame at the beginning of each section and I'd like the table of contents before the opening slide

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem...

Comment: I simply want the layout I described, I don't get what you don't understand

Comment: Ok: there is no solution to an ill-posed problem....

Comment: Not sure why you're saying it's ill-posed though

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Shade past sections in toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354411/shade-past-sections-in-toc)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\mypause}[1][+]{\onslide<#1>}
\newcounter{nextsection}

\newcommand{\sectionendtoc}{%
    \setcounter{nextsection}{\value{section}}
    \addtocounter{nextsection}{1}

    \begin{frame}<\value{nextsection}>
        \setbeamercovered{%
           still covered={\opaqueness<1->{100}},
           again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}
        }
        \let\pause\mypause
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\sectionendtoc

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\sectionendtoc

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I've tried, but it doesn't work with more than 2 sections, if you try three and print the toc on the second section you'll notice

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo Then please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem.

Comment: I can't make an example because I can't reproduce what I want, otherwise I would have just done it, anyway I put an image hoping to clarify my intent

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, I want the previous and the current sections shadowed and the following sections highlighted